# Django-firebird can not work

Tags: python, firebird

I downloaded the folder and put it into `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\firebird`,but when I use it,give me a

```
error:django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'firebird' isn't an available database backend.
Try using `django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
    'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named firebird.base
```

I have already write the path into `PYTHONPATH`.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Django 1.3 (or higher) and follow the instructions on the [django-firebird](http://code.google.com/p/django-firebird/) page.

Django 1.4 uses the [django-firebird driver on github](https://github.com/maxirobaina/django-firebird)

In your `settings.py` file, use something similar to this...

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'testdb',
        'USER': 'testdb_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'testdbpassw',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'fb': {
        'ENGINE': 'firebird',
        'NAME': '/home/idle/mydb.gdb',
        'USER': 'SYSDBA',
        'PASSWORD': 'passw',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3050',
        'OPTIONS': {'charset':'WIN1251', 'dialect':1} ,
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using?  Is `django-firebird` in the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: My django version is 1.4,and PYTHONPATH is :C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\firebird;

Comment: I do not know why,but it works well now.Maybe is PYTHONPATH`s problem.Thank you very much!

Comment: In general you should not use dialect 1, but dialect 3. Dialect 1 is an older dialect which is not entirely SQL compliant and lacks some of the newer functionality of Firebird. Just make sure your database is dialect 3 as well!

Comment: For django 1.4 the driver is in github https://github.com/maxirobaina/django-firebird

Answer (score 0):

I have updated instructions for django 1.4 and ubuntu https://github.com/mariuz/django-firebird/blob/master/README.md

I will clean the readme later and merge it with the master branch

In your case you need to put the firebird dir from the driver in both directories

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django‌​\contrib\gis\db\backends
and in 
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

Seems that later it needs the compiler and it loads it from the firebird module 
Also you will need kinterbasdb 
http://www.ibphoenix.com/download/connectivity/python