# Using firebird with django

Tags: python, django, firebird

I'm starting to learn the django framework, but I'm having trouble setting a firebird databse with it, and most answers in Overflow are outdated for django 3.0.

Is there anywhere a beginner on front-end development may look?

Answer (score 0):

First,
What FireBird you are use ? FireBird 2.5 or FireBird 3 ?

If use FireBird 2.5 you need install [FireBird 2.5](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5/) , after [FDB](https://pypi.org/project/fdb/) and [Django-FireBird](https://pypi.org/project/django-firebird/).

**FireBird 2.5 and modules works Django 1.3>=2.0.9**

You will need [Integrate Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/) and this link [Django book - legacy database](https://django-book.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter18.html)

Link: [Django-firebird can not work - StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930701/django-firebird-can-not-work)

**See ya,**